# Drawing from different distributions without looping in R

Tags: r, vector, sample, montecarlo

I want to vectorize the way I draw.  Suppose I have a vector of parameter values for poisson, and for each parameter, I want to draw 1 sample.  Is there a way to do this without looping?

Comment: `rpois` is vectorized already.

Comment: How do you do that?  rpois(1,vector)?  That does not draw 1 for each element in vector.

Comment: Reading `?rpois` might help answer that.

Comment: I did, couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify vectors for each function argument in order to obtain a vector result:

```
> rpois(rep(1,4), lambda = c(1,10,100,1000))
[1]    0   12   88 1031
```

Regarding the first argument, see [the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Poisson.html):

> The length of the result is determined by n for rpois, and is the maximum of the lengths of the numerical parameters for the other functions.
>
> The numerical parameters other than n are recycled to the length of the result. Only the first elements of the logical parameters are used.

If you need multiple draws at each level, then you'll have to `mapply` (or `Vectorize`) the function:

```
> mapply(rpois, rep(4,4), lambda = c(1,10,100,1000))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    8   78 1016
[2,]    0   10  106 1044
[3,]    1   14   97 1004
[4,]    0   13   94  983
```

Comment: What is the rep doing?  When you do rep(111111,4),.. it gives the same result. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `mapply/Map` will recycle arguments where necessary. `Map(rpois, 4, c(1,10,100,1000) )` will cut the mustard.